# How to extract first and last name from a string

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out the regex with powershell, and can't seem to get what I want.

Given the string...

```
John Doe - Specialist - Data - Person
```

I want to extract the first and list name from this string and add it to an array. I am trying the following...

```
$firstName = @()
$lastName = @()
$string = 'John Doe - Specialist - Data - Person'

$firstName += $string -replace '\s+*','' #does not work
$lastName += $string -replace '\*\s+\*','\*' #does not work
```

## Update

So far, this works...

```
$firstName, $lastName = $string -split "\s"
$lastName, $junk = $lastName -split "\s"
$firstNames += $firstName
$lastNames += $lastName
```

But it's messy, and I want to know if there is a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = 'John Doe - Specialist - Data - Person'
$firstName = $string.split(" ")[0]
$lastName = $string.split(" ")[1]
$firstName
$lastName
```

This will output

```
John
Doe
```

It splits on space and selects the first and last name

Edit based on your Code:

```
$string = 'John Doe - Specialist - Data - Person'
$firstNames += $string.split(" ")[0]
$lastNames += $string.split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually changed it to this `$string.split("\s+")[0]` just in case the user accidentally input more than 1 whitespace.

Comment: just as a question, I'm getting this string from a csv file. So when I try `$_StringName.split(" ")[0]`, It doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: havent tested it but I think you need `$_.StringName.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: Your right. So hardcoding that whitespace, will it detect 1 or more whitespaces (in between text) or just 1 whitespace (in between text)? Nevermind, I just added whitespaces and it still works. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
PS C:\scripts> $fullname = "John Mathew Kenneth"    
PS C:\scripts> $firstname, $lastname = $fullname -split " " , 2    
PS C:\scripts> $firstname
John
PS C:\scripts> $lastname
Mathew Kenneth
```